# Convert string to correct charset

Tags: python, django, soap, suds, python-unicode

Im trying to save unicode data to an external webservice.

When I try to save `æ-ø-å`, it get saved as `Ã¦-Ã¸-Ã¥` in the external system.

## Edit:

(My firstname value is `Jørn`) (Value from django `J\\xf8rn`)

`firstname.value=user_firstname` = `JÃ¸rn`

Here is my result if I try to use encode:

`firstname.value=user_firstname.encode('ascii', 'replace')` = `J?rn`

`firstname.value=user_firstname.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')` = `J&#248;rn`

`firstname.value=user_firstname.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')` = `J\xf8rn`

`firstname.value=user_firstname.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` = I get a unicode error using ignore.

My form for updating a user:

```
def show_userform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        form = UserForm(request.POST, request.user)

        
        if form.is_valid():
            u = UserProfile.objects.get(username = request.user)

            
            firstname = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            lastname = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            
            tasks.update_webservice.delay(user_firstname=firstname, user_lastname=lastname)
            

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thank-you/')

    else:
        form = UserForm(instance=request.user) # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'myapp/form.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Here is my task:

```
from suds.client import Client

@task()
def update_webservice(user_firstname, user_lastname):

    membermap = client.factory.create('ns2:Map')

    firstname = client.factory.create('ns2:mapItem')
    firstname.key="Firstname"
    firstname.value=user_firstname

    lastname = client.factory.create('ns2:mapItem')
    lastname.key="Lastname"
    lastname.value=user_lastname


    membermap.item.append(firstname)
    membermap.item.append(lastname)


    d = dict(CustomerId='xxx', Password='xxx', PersonId='xxx', ContactData=membermap)


    try:
        #Send updates to SetPerson function
        result = client.service.SetPerson(**d)
    except WebFault, e:
        print e
```

What do I need to do, to make the data saved correctly?

Comment: What is `user_firstname`?

Comment: user_firstname is from my UserForm

Answer (score 0):

Your external system is interpreting your UTF-8 as if it were Latin-1, or maybe Windows-1252. That's bad.

Encoding or decoding ASCII is not going to help. Your string is definitely not plain ASCII.

If you're lucky, it's just that you're missing some option in that web service's API, with which you could tell it that you're sending it UTF-8.

If not, you've got quite a maintenance headache on your hands, but you can still fix what you get back. The web service took the string you encoded as UTF-8 and decoded it as Latin-1, so you just need to do the exact reverse of that:

```
user_firstname = user_firstname.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `decode` and `encode` methods for `str` type.
for example :

```
x = "this is a test" # ascii encode 
x = x.encode("utf-8") # utf-8 encoded
x = x.decode("utf-8") # ascii encoded
```

Comment: When I try to do: `firstname.value=user_firstname.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')` I get this error: `UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'\xe6-\xf8-\xe5-', 6, 7, 'ordinal not in range(128)')`

Comment: This advice is simply wrong. You can't "encode" from ASCII to UTF-8, and you can't "decode" from UTF-8 to ASCII. You can only decode to Unicode and encode to either ASCII or UTF-8 (or another encoding).

Comment: we can encode from ascii to utf-8. Because UTF-8 encoded of ascii characters is same and we have no data loss.

Comment: But I don't need to convert from ascii to utf-8 (I think). Seems like I need to convert unicode characters like `\\xf8` to `ø`

Comment: \xf8 is not unicode character. It is a simple byte. What is encoding of original data? When you use decode method, it converts data to unicode and then you can convert from unicode to other formats if conversion be possible. For example you cannot convert "\u0633" unicode character to latin-1, but you can convert it to utf-8 and it's value is '\xd8\xb3'.

Comment: The data/string/value is native unicode from Django. When I try to save the character "ø" in native unicode from django (without any encoding/decoding) it gets saved as "Ã¸" in the external system. I was hoping there was a way I could encode or decode my value so it gets saved as "ø" in the external system also.

Comment: Hesam, `\xf8` is a Unicode character too. It's the same character as `\u00f8`, which is `ø`.